# Get a hard query from django orm. Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have two models, Project and ShareProject. I need to list project where ShareProject.user = request.user. I am confused how can I get this queryset.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16, verbose_name='название', blank=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prototype = models.ForeignKey('Prototype', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    colors = jsonfield.JSONField()


class SharedProject(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field='email', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='from_user')
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field='email', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='to_user')
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='share_project')
    permission = jsonfield.JSONField()
    all_users = models.BooleanField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to traverse the reverse relationships. Please [check out the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects), they provide an immense amount of information.

```
from django.db.models import Q
related_projects = Project.objects.filter(
    Q(share_project__to_user=request.user)
    | Q(share_project__from_user=request.user)
)
```

Your question didn't match your model regarding `ShareProject.user`, so I created a queryset that ORs the two user references together. I don't think this is exactly what you want, but I'm hopeful you'll be able to use this as a jumping off point.

Answer (score 1):

It should be simple like this.

```py
projects = [share_project.project for share_project in SharedProject.objects.filter(to_user__id = request.user)]
```